# ZendFatal error: Class 'Zend\Ldap\Ldap' not found

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, zend-framework2, ldap

So, i'm trying to make a Ldap authentication, following the docs in

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

I just replace the 'Album' module with a 'Auth' module  and use the sample code for Ldap autentication

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.ldap.html

but i'm getting this error where Zend can't find the Ldap class when i submit the form with the login data.

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Ldap\Ldap' not found in C:\wamp\www\sade\vendor\zendframework\zend-authentication\src\Adapter\Ldap.php on line 139

I'm using composer, for the zend framework and the atuoloader for the modules, i already have errors related a class not found but my own classes, not Zend classes like Ldap.

Thanks.

Here is the structure of the files and folders

```
/module
     /Auth
         /config
            module.config.php
         /src
             /Auth
                 /Controller
                    AuthController.php
                 /Form
                    AuthForm.php
                 /Model
                 Auth.php
         /view
             /auth
                 /auth
                    index.php
        Module.php
```

And the main code of the module:

**module.config.php**

```
 return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Auth\Controller\Auth' => 'Auth\Controller\AuthController',
     ),
 ),
'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'auth' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/auth[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Auth\Controller\Auth',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

 'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'auth' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
);
```

**AuthController.php**

```
//AuthController.php
namespace Auth\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\Ldap as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Config\Reader\Ini as ConfigReader;
use Zend\Config\Config;
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer\Stream as LogWriter;
use Zend\Log\Filter\Priority as LogFilter;

use Auth\Model\Auth;  
use Auth\Form\AuthForm; 

 class AuthController extends AbstractActionController
 {
     public function indexAction()
     {
     $form = new AuthForm();
     $form->get('submit')->setValue('index');
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
        $Auth = new Auth();
        $Auth->username = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username');
        $Auth->password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');


        $AuthenticationService = new AuthenticationService();

        $configReader = new ConfigReader();
        $configData = $configReader->fromFile('config/ldap-config.ini');
        $config = new Config($configData, true);
        $log_path = $config->production->ldap->log_path;
        //die($log_path)."--";
        $options = $config->production->ldap->toArray();
        unset($options['log_path']);

        $adapter = new AuthAdapter($options,
                                   $Auth->username,
                                   $Auth->password);

        $form->setInputFilter($Auth->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        $result = $AuthenticationService->authenticate($adapter);

            if ($log_path) {
                    $messages = $result->getMessages();

                    $logger = new Logger;
                    $writer = new LogWriter($log_path);

                    $logger->addWriter($writer);

                    $filter = new LogFilter(Logger::DEBUG);
                    $writer->addFilter($filter);

                    foreach ($messages as $i => $message) {
                        if ($i-- > 1) { // $messages[2] and up are log messages
                            $message = str_replace("\n", "\n  ", $message);
                            $logger->debug("Ldap: $i: $message");
                        }
                    }
                }                 
            //return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
     }
     return array('form' => $form);

 }

 public function LoginAction()
 {
 }
 public function LogoutAction()

 {
 }
 }
```

**AuthForm.php**

```
//AuthForm.php

namespace Auth\Form;

 use Zend\Form\Form;

 class AuthForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
     // we want to ignore the name passed
     parent::__construct('auth');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'username',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Nombre de usuario',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'password',
         'type' => 'Password',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Contraseña',
         ),
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Iniciar sesión',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
 }
 }
```

**Auth.php** (inside Model folder, for filters that i may implement later)

```
namespace Auth\Model;

 // Add these import statements
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

 class Auth implements InputFilterAwareInterface
 {
 public $username;
 public $password;
 protected $inputFilter;                       // <-- Add this variable

 public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
     $this->username = (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : null;
     $this->password  = (isset($data['password']))  ? $data['password']  : null;
 }

 // Add content to these methods:
 public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
 {
     throw new \Exception("Not used");
 }

 public function getInputFilter()
 {
     if (!$this->inputFilter) {
         $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'username',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 100,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ));

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'password',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 100,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ));

         $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
     }

     return $this->inputFilter;
 }
}
```

**And Module.php**, i don't think that index.phtml needs to be posted here.

```
 namespace Auth;

 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
 use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

 class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
 {
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {

 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
     return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }
 }
```

Comment: How did you install ZendFramework? Did you install the complete framework? Or just some modules? For me it looks more like an issue with the autoloader than with your app.

Comment: I install the whole framework with composer, folowing the docs in https://zf2-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/installation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Zend\Ldap` is not included any more in a default installation. As the ZendFramework-Team has splitted the zendframework into multiple components not all of them are needed any more. And `Zend\Ldap` is one of the "not needed" ones as it has a hard dependency on `ext/ldap` as you can't use it without the LDAP-extension of PHP. For details on that have a look at https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/7569

You should therefore run `composer require zendframework/zend-ldap` from the base-directory of your project and you should be up and running. By now you get that as a suggestions after the installation.

```
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zend-ldap (zend-ldap component ~2.5.0, if you need LDAP features)
```

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is a part of core of zf2.

If you have problems with class Name, then you habe some problems with your autoloader config or with incorrect class name paths.

Comment: Yes, i think that the problem is related to a autoloader config, but i don't know where to start looking for a solution, i'm not sure is this is a namespaces problem or a problem with the psr-0 autoloader in the composer files inside the framework