# ZF3 - composer require module -> module could not be initialised

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-framework-modules

I am working with the skeleton-application as a base, using the Vagrant / Composer setup. After the initial install I realised I would need the LDAP module. I then ran `composer require zendframework/zend-ldap` which ran successfully and I have located the files in `~/vendor/zendframework/zend-ldap`.

The issue is when I add `'Zend\Ldap'` to my `~/config/modules.config.php` I encounter the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Zend\Ldap) could not be initialized. in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php:203 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#1 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Zend\\Ldap') #2 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php(120): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#5 /var/www/vendor/zendfr in /var/www/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleManager.php on line 203
```

The **`~/config/modules.config.php`** file:

```
/**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Zend\Ldap',    // All is well if this is commented out
    'Application', 

];
```

and the **`~/config/application.config.php`** file:

```
/**
 * If you need an environment-specific system or application configuration,
 * there is an example in the documentation
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-system-configuration
 * @see https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#environment-specific-application-configuration
 */
return [
    // Retrieve list of modules used in this application.
    'modules' => require __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => [
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => [
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ],

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        'config_cache_key' => 'application.config.cache',

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'application.module.cache',

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache/',

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ],

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    // 'service_listener_options' => [
    //     [
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ],
    // ],

    // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
    // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
    // 'service_manager' => [],
];
```

I have tried removing cache folder, running `composer update`, restarting Vagrant, adding the full path to the `'modules_path'` array in `application.config.php` but it is always the same error. Interestingly I run into the same issue with `'Zend\View'` that was included from the install, but a module such as `'Zend\Session'` can be added to the `modules.config.php` file with no issues (They are all located in the `vendor/zendframework` directory)

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Comment: Disable all the 5 cache related options in the `application.config.php` by commenting out. Delete those already cached files. Now the main one, uncomment `Zend\Ldap` and run composer update command.

Comment: I commented out the cache options and ran `composer update` but unfortunately I am still receiving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend\Ldap` is one of the ZF components. As it does not have a `Module.php` in its `/src` directory which is mandatory for a module. So you do not need to initialize like other modules through `modules.config.php` to use it in your application.

This component is not included as required with default installation of ZF. So if you want to use any component, you must add them to autoloader. Once you added a component like this one `composer require zendframework/zend-ldap` in your project, you would then be able to use it.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144686/7935051) and [this issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/pull/7571) to be clear!

Answer (score 2):

zend-ldap doesn't have a src/Module.php file, so you can't add it as a module. Also it doesn't seem to include a standard factory so you need to write one yourself. More info on how to set it up:

https://zendframework.github.io/zend-ldap/intro/

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, zend-ldap does not provide a `Module` class; it is simply a component that provides functionality. It has no service definitions, which is why there is no `Module` class.

Two things to note:

- Install zendframework/zend-component-installer in your application: `composer require --dev zendframework/zend-component-installer`. When you do, any time you add another component to your application that exposes a `Module` class, it will prompt you, asking if you want to add it to your application configuration. (zend-component-installer is installed by default if you start your project with the zendframework/skeleton-application.)
- We have recently opened our [Zend Framework forums](https://discourse.zendframework.com); consider directing your ZF questions there in the future, to make the answers easily discoverable for ZF users.

Answer (score 1):

Is `zend-ldap` included in your project? If not Run in your terminal

```
composer require zendframework/zend-ldap
```

And you can disable caching in development process by enabling development mode: `composer development-enable`

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I mentioned in the first paragraph I began by running that command and I also confirmed the files are in the vendor/zendframework directory. I am also currently in developer mode, I double checked with `composer development-status`. Could you think of any other reason it wouldn't be able to initialise the module?

Comment: How I know, if you're installing module via composer you needn't add module name in ~/config/modules.config.php . You just use it.